# Por que de segunda-feira a sexta-feira existe a palavra "feira" nos dias da semana?

Tags: ortografia, significado, etimologia

Os nomes dos dias da semana em português são:

> - domingo
> - segunda-feira
> - terça-feira
> - quarta-feira
> - quinta-feira
> - sexta-feira
> - sábado

Qual a origem e significado desses nomes?

Por que de segunda-feira a sexta-feira existe a palavra "**feira**" nos dias da semana?

Comment: Boa pergunta, Denis.  Também gostaria de saber.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Vem de "dia de descanso", do latim Feria. O bispo Martinho de Braga, em 563, decidiu que os nomes dos dias de semanas deveriam ser assim. Inicialmente, deveria valer apenas para os dias que antecedem o domingo de Páscoa (Semana Santa), mas foi adotado pelo portugueses para o ano inteiro, com exceção do Sábado (do hebreu Shabbat) e Domingo (do latim Dies Dominicus).

Tem uma boa resposta em http://mundoestranho.abril.com.br/materia/por-que-os-dias-da-semana-tem-feira-no-nome.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Hebrew Bible (Torah) *Sábado* (Shabbat) is the Jewish rest day (equivalent to Sunday for Christians and Friday for Muslims). This was the seventh day of creation, following the days that were simply enumerated in the Bible as the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th. This serves as the basis for the Hebrew names for the days of the week (still in use in modern Israel), which are literally translated as "the first day" (Monday), "the second day" (Tuesday), etc.:

| Hebrew | Arabic | Meaning | Portuguese | English |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yom rishon | el ahad | first day | domingo | Sunday |
| yom sheni | el ethneen | second day | segunda-feira | Monday |
| yom shlishi | el thulatha | third day | terça-feira | Tuesday |
| yom revii | el arbe’a | fourth day | quarta-feira | Wednesday |
| yom khamishi | el khamees | fifth day | quinta-feira | Thursday |
| yom shishi | el jouma’a | sixth day (day of prayer) | sexta-feira | Friday |
| shabbat | el sabet | shabbat | sábado | Saturday |

The Hebrew convention was adopted by the Arabs (with the exception of the name for Friday, which is the day of prayer for Muslims), and inherited from them by the Christians in the Iberian peninsula.

The alternative names for the days of the week, those used, e.g., in Spanish, French, or English have their origin in the Roman tradition, *Solis dies, Lunae dies, Martis dies, Mercurii dies, Jovis dies, Veneris dies, Saturni dies*, referring to the Sun, Moon and the pre-Christian Roman gods. The exception here are the names for Saturday and Sunday: the former adapted from its Biblical/Hebrew form, the latter meaning *Domini Dies* ("the day of the Lord") - this is also true for the names of these days in Portuguese.

See, e.g., [Religion and the seven days week](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj3wtiRjO75AhXQ3oUKHRZlDOkQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdialnet.unirioja.es%2Fdescarga%2Farticulo%2F62128.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1v0-dtxoaEuDdMUWTEeINt) for more details.

Comment: Roger, the downvote is not mine, but your post as it is (v1) indeed doesn't answer the question, which is: "Why do the days of the week have **_feira_** in them?".

Comment: @stafusa I thought about posting my own question&answer, but decided that this would be almost a duplicate, since in the body of the OP there's a more general question: *Qual a origem e significado desses nomes?*

Comment: You're right, the question **is** there and your answer is valid. On the other hand, since the question puts so much emphasis on "feira", I'd say a more general Q&A about the weekdays' names would not be a duplicate — however the community seems to think otherwise, since they closed [this question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/4426/2764). As long as it remains closed this question here does seem to be the best home available to your nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Feira vem de feria (= dia de descanso) porque as feiras costumavam ocorrer nesse dia, Domingo. Então contam-se os dias em relação ao Domingo.