# Origem das palavras do dia semana

Tags: origem

Gostaria de saber qual é a origem dos nomes dos dias da semana,

> segunda-feira, terça-feira...

Comment: Check this answer: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9412/2764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O domingo, derivado do latim "dies Dominica", dia do Senhor, é considerado o último da semana para os cristãos.
Era no dia da missa que havia maior aglomeração de pessoas e, por isso, os agricultores se reuniam em torno da igreja para vender seus produtos - o primeiro dia de feira. 
O dia seguinte, consequentemente, era o segundo, a segunda-feira. E daí por diante até chegar o sábado, cuja origem é o termo hebraico shabbatt, considerado o último da semana para os judeus.

Fonte: https://novaescola.org.br/conteudo/175/como-surgiram-os-nomes-dos-dias-da-semana